# React SetState array not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

I have a Google map in my react application which allows users to sign up (by entering their name). It then gets their location every 1 second and sends it to all the other users currently using the app.

I am trying to plot the users on a map using google-map-react. This should update every time a user is added, or their location changes and reflect this with their marker moving on the map.

It is console logging the usersArray correctly, but users is not being updated, am I doing setState wrong?

```
const Map = ({ location, zoomLevel }) => {
    const { name } = useParams();
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
    const ws = useRef();
    let [latitude, setLatitude] = useState('');
    let [longitude, setLongitude] = useState('');
    const [isConnectionOpen, setConnectionOpen] = useState(false);
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        ws.current = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8081');
        //new user has connected
        ws.current.onopen = () => {
            setConnectionOpen(true);
        };
        //sending message to other users
        ws.current.onmessage = (ev) => {
            const message = JSON.parse(ev.data);
            //update users function
            handleAddNewUser(message);
            setMessages((_messages) => [..._messages, message]);
        };
        return () => {};
    }, []);

    //checks if a message has been received my a new user. If existing user - update location
    function handleAddNewUser(message) {
        let usersArray = [];
        let newUser = true;
        if (users.length == 0) {
            usersArray.push(message);
        } else {
            for (let user of users) {
                if (message.sender == user.sender) {
                    newUser = false;
                    user = message;
                }
            }
            if (newUser == true) {
                usersArray.push(message);
            }
        }
        console.log(usersArray);
        // update the state to the updatedUsers
        setUsers(usersArray);
        console.log(users);
    } 

    //triggers the send function every 1 second
    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            send();
        }, 1000);
        return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, []);

    //sends the users location as a message to all the other users
    const send = () => {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function (position) {
                latitude = position.coords.latitude.toString();
                longitude = position.coords.longitude.toString();
                ws.current.send(JSON.stringify({ sender: name, latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude }));
                setLatitude('');
                setLongitude('');
            });
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className='map'>
            <div className='google-map'>
                <GoogleMapReact
                    bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: 'keyID' }}
                    defaultCenter={location}
                    defaultZoom={zoomLevel}>
                     users.map(user => {
                    <MyGreatPlace lat={user.latitude} 
                    lng={user.longitude} text=  
                    {user.sender} />
                 })
                </GoogleMapReact>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
export default Map;
```

Also, when plotting the users on the map, i am getting this error: Unexpected token. Did you mean {'>'} or >?

Comment: `console.log(users);` directly after `setUsers` is an empty array since setUsers is an async operation. users.map has to be wrapped in curly braces {}

Comment: @MWO thanks, how can i change the setUsers function to make users equal to whatever is in usersArray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try logging users in `useEffect` with users in the dependency array.
But you are having two `useEffects` in your component. You should only have one!

```
//triggers the send function every 1 second
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(users)
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        send();
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, [users]);
```

And to `map` render `users` you usually do it like that (as an example):

```
<GoogleMapReact bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: 'keyID' }} defaultCenter={location} defaultZoom={zoomLevel}>
    {users?.map((user: any) => {
    return <MyGreatPlace lat={user.latitude} lng={user.longitude} text={user.sender} />
    })
    }
</GoogleMapReact>
```

Comment: thank you, they are appearing in the users array now. But the markers aren't working on the map. is this wrong -  {users?.map((user, i) => (
      <MyGreatPlace key={i} lat={user.latitude} lng={user.longitude} text={user.sender} />
     ))}

Comment: @Pippa97 i have updated my code. you could give it a try like that

Comment: I am getting this error with that code - Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. i also had to remove the :any because it is a jsx file not typescript

Comment: then you can try to give it a uniqe key prop `{users?.map((user, i) => {
    return <MyGreatPlace key={i} lat={user.latitude} lng={user.longitude} text={user.sender} />
    })
    }`

Comment: now i'm not getting an error, but it's still not adding the markers to the map

Comment: yeah but what is your MyGreatPlace? does it have a height and width? did you look in devtools the html, if there are markers?

Comment: i have just added the mygreatplace.jsx code into my original question. it is using props i think to display the marker. Is this a better way to display markers? I would like the markers to be an external image with the user name on top of it

Comment: this component is not accepting any props and i dont know what it should do. but for testing purposes i would replace MyGreatPlace with a div  `<div style={{width:50, background:'green'}}>
      Marker
      </div>`

Comment: and do you actually have a api key? and is your map being displayed at all?

Comment: Yes I have an api key and my map is being displayed. Could I just eliminate mygreatplace and display an image (from my images folder) with the user.sender string on top of the image in the center)

Comment: yes sure, but i would try it with this div first `<div style={{width:50, background:'green'}}>
      {user.latitude} {user.longitude} {user.sender}
      </div>`

Comment: this warning again - Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Comment: then add the key again lol

Comment: Warning: React does not recognize the `$geoService` prop on a DOM element.

Comment: ok then i would use a functional component

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242230/discussion-between-pippa97-and-mwo).

Answer (score 2):

You should check if user exist first. Like this:

if(users){
setUsers(userArray)
}

Comment: but the usersArray is getting poupulated ok, it's this line - setUsers({ users: usersArray }); Its not making users equal to the new usersArray

Comment: Okay let me edit my answer

Comment: Hope it help you solve the problem?

Comment: You have to check if the user exist first. Because the initial state is an empty array. So when the component mount then it will change state to the data it fetched

Comment: users is still showing as an empty array with that code. usersArray is showing all the users, so i just want to do make users equal to whatever is in usersArray